# Log Shipping causes high context switches

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

MSSQL - I have setup log shipping on many databases being sent to 2 different servers in NORECOVERY mode.

This is causing crazy context switches on the main server.

Is this normal?

16 Cores without HT, 192gb ram.

Comment: I have not seen LS causing high context switches. How are u sure this is because of LS

Comment: When I enabled log shipping the spikes started, when I disabled the jobs they stopped. This was also being done on 18 databases so I'm wondering it it's because there are so many log backup jobs running at once?

Comment: What is size of all the databases are they very big and produce huge transaction log backup files

Comment: Are you clearing the backup history from MSDB? How big is MDSB?